# Is there an "exposed work" cover plate for keystone jacks/data ports?

Tags: conduit, ethernet, product-recommendation

I've run Cat 5e ethernet cable through 1/2" PVC conduit out to my shed so that I can connect a wifi extender and improve wifi coverage in my backyard. The conduit comes into the shed and elbows up to a location under the roof and away from harm. I'd like to terminate it with an rj45 keystone jack that I can plug my extender into.

With something like mains power, I can connect the conduit to a handy box and then attach a metal cover over my receptacle:

[image: receptacle cover]

However, I can't seem to find a similar product for keystone data jacks. I tried a regular plastic data port wall plate, but it doesn't seem to sit properly on the handy box as it's made to attach to some other kind of box. I could always take a blank metal cover and use my dremel to cut a custom hole for the keystone jack, but it would be easier and neater if such a product already exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if the exact match you're looking for exists, but you can get decora inserts (for the type of plate in your picture) that fit one, two, or three keystones. It'll be plastic rather than metal, but the plastic will match the keystones while the  metal matches the box.

[image: one-hole keystone decora insert from cable wholesaler's website]